# System.import async module loading conflicts with scripts tags sync loading

Tags: node.js, jspm, systemjs, electron

I started using JSPM with atom/electron for porting a web site I've built using Marionette.

I have all my App written around Marionette modules so I want to load all the JavasSript files before starting the app.

```
<script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
<script src="config.js"></script>
<script>
    loadApp = System.import('./scripts/app_definition').then(function(m){
        window.App = m['App'];
    });
</script>

<!-- inject:js -->
    ##LOTS INJECTED SCRIPTS THAT NEEDS window.App to be defined##
    <script src="compiled/modules/video/video_app.js"></script>
<!-- endinject -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    loadApp.then(function(){
        App.start();
    })
</script>
```

I'm having problems with the Async nature of `System.import()`. How would you load the scripts after System.import has finished loading the App code?

For production I have no problem with this, because I would concatenate all the files in a single js module and the load that module using System.import, but that would be a nightmare to debug, I would prefer to have the files loaded separately.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Seems like I'd expect you to be importing `video_app` since it would have a dependency on `app_definition`, that or  you should be adding the script tag inside the import callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global variables are a big no no when using ES6 modules.

You could load your scripts after the app definition:

```
loadApp = System.import('./scripts/app_definition').then(function(m){
    window.App = m['App'];

    var scriptEl = document.createElement('script');
    scriptEl.src = "compiled/modules/video/video_app.js";
    document.head.appendChild(scriptEl);
});
```

But i'm not sure what's the use of having JSPM here in the first place. So the real solution would be to transform all your modules to ES6 import syntax and avoid global variables all together.